# How can I investigate SQLAlchemy QueuePool limit overflow?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I get

> TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30

I have seen the questions:

- [Sql Alchemy QueuePool limit overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24956894/562769)
- [SQLAlchemy raises QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38822829/562769)

as well as their answers. I tried them and I tried to reproduce my problem in a [very simplified codebase](https://github.com/MartinThoma/demo-sqlalchemy). I can't reproduce it.

**What can I do to find / fix the problem?**

For example, can I get the current "usage" of the QueuePool within Python?

(Also, but probably better another question: Why shouldn't I set the queue overflow to -1?)

What I didn't try so far is setting `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE']` (to be set [here](https://github.com/MartinThoma/demo-sqlalchemy/blob/master/web/foo_submodule/app.py#L39-L45)). I guess I would have to set it to a low value in order to fix this problem, but I might get timeouts in other places then, right?

Answer (score 2):

1. Run `show PROCESSLIST` against your MySQL database to show the connections / pool / usage.

   - In PyCharm, open the "Database" sidebar (usually on the right side), then right-click on your database / schema and select "Open Console". Paste in the command above and click the green "Execute" button.
   - What I noticed was that when I was using the API, each API call would open up a separate connection, and when they hit 20 connections, the next API call would cause the error, which would say `TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached` (10 + 10 = 20).
   - When I got rid of `threaded=True`, I only ever saw one connection open.
2. Commit or stash all of your existing changes, then create a branch and start stripping out code / simplifying your app piece-by-piece and seeing if the issue still pops up.

   - I didn't use this technique in this case, but I've used it successfully when dealing with other seriously-hard-to-track-down bugs like this.
   - Since you mentioned not being able to reproduce the issue with a simple example, I figured it'd be worth suggesting this technique as a way of arriving at a minimal example.
3. (In combination with #2) Try reducing the `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE` Flask-SQLAlchemy setting to make it quicker to reproduce the bug.

   - The idea here is to make the crash happen sooner.
   - I didn't do this in this case.

Comment: Hm, I'll check that tomorrow. If you don't have `threaded=True`, will multiple users then be able to use the site at the same time (even if there are long-running queries)?

Comment: My understanding is that your *dev* server will not be able to handle multiple requests concurrently, but that your *prod* server should be using a WSGI server like `gunicorn` or `uWSGI` that will be able to spawn multiple instances of your app.

To elaborate on the "your prod should be using a WSGI server": I looked at the Flask source and for the `run()` function it says "Do not use `run()` in a production setting. It is not intended to meet security and performance requirements for a production server." You can also see them say that here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/

Comment: Ok, but I don't use app.run anyway (see the link). I use WSGIServer

Comment: Hmm...then I guess all I can offer are my "How to investigate the issue" tips.

Comment: In the interest of keeping this question on-topic, I've moved the "my situation" and "how I fixed it" parts of my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47151701/4115031